# Why does tmux/byobu fill my screen with garbage characters when I copy a selection?

Tags: byobu, tmux

When I copy a selection from tmux with a window split, my screen fills up with garbage characters.  Depending on the size of the selection, it could be a lot, or just one line.  The following images demonstrate:

[image: Selection Area]

Then after hitting  to make the selection:

[image]

Notice all the garbage characters on the right pane.

How do I get rid of this behavior?

Comment: how are you able to select only half pane? is there a setting ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an option `set-clipboard` that will try to copy your selection to the x-clipboard with an escape sequence.

```
:set-option -s set-clipboard off
```

gnome-terminal does not support this method of using the clipboard, which is the default terminal in Ubuntu.

Comment: This actually bothered me for a long time (years), and I have finally run across the answer through trial-and-error and running byobu in an xterm.  I noticed when I opened byobu/tmux in xterm, I didn't get these characters printed to screen.  So, I searched the manual for what it could be.

Comment: Thank you! This was bugging me for ... well, weeks now. :)

Comment: This solution does not work for xfce (XUbuntu 16.04) terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Edit `~/.tmux.conf` or with Byobu `$HOME/.byobu/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g set-clipboard off
```

- Reference on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tmux/comments/2xgrf8/garbage_characters_printed_to_screen_after_a/).